# TypeScript import across multiple files with same module name

Tags: typescript

Whilst getting to grips with TypeScript's module import/export system, *which STILL eludes me, and feels like a dark art mastered only by he who must not be named...* I'm trying to understand how I can make the following import a little cleaner

**B.ts**

```
export module System {
    export class Bravo {
        constructor(n: number) {
            console.log(`Bravo ${n}`);
        }
    }
}
```

**A.ts**

```
import {System as System1} from "./B";

export module System {
    export class Alpha extends System1.Bravo {
        constructor() { 
            super(123);
        }
    }
}
```

**What don't I like about this**

- `import { System as System1 }`
- `extends System1.Bravo`

That to me, sticks out like a sore thumb! Is there any way to make it cleaner?

- `import { System.Bravo } from "./B";`
- `extends Bravo`

Something like this?

**As a side-note**, what I'm actually trying to achieve is

- Proper use of namespacing i.e. `System.Foo.Bar.MyAwesomeClass`.
- Separating classes into their own files so that builds don't include things they dont need.
- *With regards to above, tree shaking?*
- Using export/import as a mechanism to manage dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a different approach, but should produce the same result you're looking for.

Instead of having a module `System`, you can use the file system to put all the files in a conjoined module with an `index.ts` file. So have a directory called `System`. So do something like this:

`/System/Bravo.ts`

```
export default class Bravo {
  constructor(n: number) {
    console.log(`Bravo ${n}`);
  }
}
```

`/System/Alpha.ts`

```
import Bravo from "./Bravo"

export default class Alpha extends Bravo {
  constructor() { 
    super(123);
  }
}
```

Then include an `index.ts` file that includes both.

`/System/index.ts`

```
import Alpha from "./Alpha";
import Bravo from "./Bravo";

export { Alpha };
export { Bravo };
```

Then, whenever you want to import the entire module you would do:

```
import * as System from "<relativePath>/System";

let alphaClass = new System.Alpha();
let bravoClass = new System.Bravo(1);
```

Likewise, if you just want `Alpha`, then you can import it directly like so:

```
import { Alpha } from "<relativePath>/System";

let alphaClass = new Alpha();
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the actual emitted code in this case does not exist within a module, or namespace (still not entirely sure of the difference), so how do I use this to segregate my types away from the global scope?

Comment: Like you, the module system is voodoo to me. I keep seeing that "module" is deprecated and you should use "namespace" instead, so I don't use "module" keyword.

Comment: If you're worried about type collisions, you can use the same name for different class types without a collision. With the "default" keyword, you can actually name them whatever you want when you import them unless you import them in the curly brackets like `{ Alpha }`.  In which case you would have to do `{ Alpha as AnotherAlpha }`. But otherwise, you could import the `Alpha` class like `import MySuperAwesomeClass from "./System/Alpha"` and it will use it as `MySuperAwesomeClass`.